Deleted ubuntu folder on EFI, still appears on startup
Recently I deleted my ubuntu partition on dual boot, resizing my Macintosh HD partition correctly. Moreover, I also deleted the ubuntu folder on EFI folder after I mounted disk0s1, but the problem is that EFI boot still appears on startup, and I dont know why as I deleted that folder.

This is what still appears on EFI folder, I don't want to delete any other thing until I know the answer in case I completely destroy my PC.
Also, if I try to select EFI boot on startup, Mac crashes and restarts
Edit: I have a MacBook Pro 13 inches from 2015 running Monterrey 12.7.6.
The Ubuntu I had on dual-boot was 24.04

The BOOT folder was created when you installed Ubuntu. You can delete this folder. If you want to verify, then first rename BOOT to BOOTX. Either way, the EFI boot should no longer appear on startup.
